# AJAX request to append to different DIVs

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am having problems with appending additional input fields on a page, each of which when appended also has jquery code to append further select boxes related to them. The basic html structure is as follows:

```
<p id="add_field"> … </p>
<div class="show_sub_categories">
    <div id="sub_cat_1">
    <select class="parent" name="search_category"> … </select>
    <select class="parent" name="sub_category"> … </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show_sub_categories">
    <div id="sub_cat_2">
    <select class="parent" name="search_category"> … </select>
    <select class="parent" name="sub_category"> … </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code below does append select boxes but not formatted correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //$('#loader').hide();

    $('.parent').livequery('change', function() {
        var div = $(".parent").closest("div").attr("id");
        $(this).nextAll('.parent').remove();
        $(this).nextAll('input').remove();

        $('#' + div).append('<img src="images/system/loader2323.gif" style="float:left" id="loader" alt="" />');

        $.post("get_chid_categories.php", {
            parent_id: $(this).val(),
        }, function(response){

            setTimeout(function () { finishAjax(div, response); }, 400);
        });

        return false;
    });
});

function finishAjax(div, response){
    $('#loader').remove();

    $('#'+div).append(unescape(response));
}
```

get_chid_categories.php simply contains code for the `sub_category` box, the contents of which are determined by the parent_id passed to it.

I have another append function which adds the `show_sub_categories`, sub_cat_'num' and the search category select box.

Everything on the page works perfectly for the first append ie the `search_cateogry`, sub_category boxes and the loading gif position correctly. My problem is that with subsequent appends of `.show_sub_categories`, when the search_category box is changed to run the 'change' function in my code above, the loader gif and the associated `sub_category` select boxes are appended to the first `div`. I can't understand for the life of me why it is still doing this as surely the search_category box appended to the page second is sitting in the `<div id="sub_cat_2">`, third search category box appended would be within `#sub_cat_3` etc etc, therefore when div is defined...

```
var div = $(".parent").closest("div").attr("id");
```

...the `div` id should also be `#sub_cat_2`, and then surely that would mean the loader gif and the `sub_category` select box would both append correctly within my `<div id="sub_cat_2">`. As said, at the moment the formatting is totally bizaare as irrespective of how many appends are made, everything is appended to the first `div` (***`#sub_cat_1`***). Please help, I'm tearing my hair out! Welly.

Since posting this question originally I've managed to define `div` and use closest to get the name of the `div` the select box is sitting in.

Answer (score 0):

you're quite close to it:

```
var pid = $(this).attr('id');

$.post("get_chid_categories.php", {
        parent_id: pid,
    }, function(response){

        setTimeout(function () { finishAjax(pid, response); }, 400);
});
```

setTimeout accepts an anonymous function which is easier to code. And then you may pass the current id to all subsequent functions, having the entire code more generic.

Comment: Many thanks @Axel Amthor for your response, it is unfortunately not working though. Also, how would I append the loader.gif to the correct show_sub_categories div? Would I define pid earlier in the function and then use $('#show_sub_categories'+ pid).append ?

Comment: pid should be the id of one of the divs already, so it should be like `$('#'+ pid).append(...`. In order to get that fully coded, the HTML is needed (i.e. the hierarchy of the divs and where the handlers are attached to).

Comment: Thanks again @Axel Amthor. I think it doesn't work as pid is defined as $(this).attr('id'), but is $this not the .parent tag in this case? I need the name of the div that the select box (with class of .parent) is sitting inside.

Comment: without seeing the DOM structure its hard for me to tell who is who's sibling, child, parent ...